# Can't install CUDA drivers for GeForce GT555M

Tags: cuda

I've just bought a new Asus n55 laptop. It has 2 graphics cards from Intel and NVIDIA. But when I try to install CUDA's developer driver for my GPU I get this error:

> "This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware".

I have downloaded both of the following files but both of them get mentioned error:

- Developer Drivers for WinVista and Win7 (270.81)
- Notebook Developer Drivers for WinVista and Win7 (275.33)

How can I fix this problem? Actually how can I develop CUDA programs on my NVIDIA GPU?

Comment: And when i run a compiled cuda program i get this error :/ cudaSafeCall() Runtime API error 35: CUDA driver version
is insufficient for CUDA runtime version.

Comment: Which version do you have installed currently? (developer or no developer)

Comment: As I said i can't install developer version. I just tried to run a cuda program without this driver but i got error. Actually I compiled one of the CUDA samples with VS2008 and tried to run it.

Comment: This was referenced in Über meta question *[The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/)*. But why isn't there a trace of it? Changed within the edit grace period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the drivers from Asus themselves?  I thought a laptop using [Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html) would report both the graphics cards properly but it may be that you need the drivers from the manufacturer.

From what I can tell the driver version on the Asus website is 268.74 and you can get it [here](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Multimedia_Entertainment/N55SF/#download).

As a side note, in order to actually *use* the nVidia CUDA drivers you may need to somehow push the system into Optimus mode as it may be that the Nvidia is deactivated when not in use, perhaps you need to start some DirectX app first...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah I have downloaded this driver from Asus and it has been installed but it doesn't have any effect and i can run any cuda program.:(

Answer (score 0):

you might be on the wrong graphic card. You should switch to NVIDIA one permanently to be able to install it. Just check if whether that's the problem.